# How to reopen previous session of Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, I would like to reopen my previous session when I start the browser again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome settings, in the "On start-up" section, choose "Continue where you left off."

[image: Continue where you left off]

Answer (score 0):

What I do sometimes is: leave Chrome open when you power off your computer, and the next time you open it you will have a message asking if you want to reload the pages you had opened.